# you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' in Line 1

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I tried to insert following data to the database. but it gives me the above 
this error.
you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' in Line 1.

i tried several things but it is not fixing.

```
  try{
         Statement stat = Database.getStatement();
         stat.executeUpdate("INSERT  INTO"+" admission"+
             " (a_id,sickness,recPhysicianDetails,
                admittedDate,Patient_ID,Doctor_id,Doctor_id1)"+" 
              VALUES
               ('"+txt1.getText()+"',
                '"+txt7.getText()+"','"+txt8.getText()+"', '"+txt6.getText()+"',
 (  SELECT  ID  FROM  patient  WHERE  Patient_name='"+txt3.getText()+"' ),
 (  SELECT  ID  FROM  employee WHERE  Name='"+txt9.getText()+"' ),
 (  SELECT  ID  FROM  employee WHERE  Name='"+txt10.getText()+"')"  );

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You have `''` before `txt6.getText()`... that is two `'` characters in a row. Remove one of them.

Comment: To avoid this problems, you have to use PrepapredStatement

Comment: One bracket is missing in the query String try this one. stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO"+" admission"+"
 (a_id,sickness,recPhysicianDetails,admittedDate,Patient_ID,Doctor_id,Doctor_id1)"+" VALUES('"+txt1.getText()+"','"+txt7.getText()+"','"+txt8.getText()+"',
'"+txt6.getText()+"',(SELECT ID FROM patient WHERE Patient_name='"+txt3.getText()+"'),(SELECT ID FROM employee WHERE Name='"+txt9.getText()+"'),(SELECT ID FROM employee WHERE Name='"+txt10.getText()+"'))");

Comment: Instead of concatenating values into a query string, which leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use prepared statements with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, quotation marks (`'`) are not rightly placed, plus there is a missing closing bracket in the end. Using `PreparedStatement` will make sure you don't need to worry about quotation marks, try this:

```
Connection conn = //get connection
PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  admission (a_id,sickness,recPhysicianDetails,admittedDate,Patient_ID,Doctor_id,Doctor_id1)"
+" VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, (SELECT ID FROM patient WHERE Patient_name = ?),(SELECT ID FROM employee WHERE Name = ?),(SELECT ID FROM employee WHERE Name = ?))");
stat.setString(1, txt1.getText());
stat.setString(2, txt7.getText());
stat.setString(3, txt8.getText());
stat.setString(4, txt6.getText());
stat.setString(5, txt3.getText());
stat.setString(6, txt9.getText());
stat.setString(7, txt10.getText());
stat.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use prepared statement instead directly calling the value from the textbox.

```
 try{
     Statement stat = Database.getStatement();
     stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO admission"+
     "(a_id,sickness,recPhysicianDetails,admittedDate,Patient_ID,Doctor_id,Doctor_id1)"+
     " VALUES('"+txt1.getText()+"','"+txt7.getText()+"','"+txt8.getText()+"','"+txt6.getText()+"',"+
     "(SELECT ID FROM patient WHERE Patient_name='"+txt3.getText()+"'),"+
     "(SELECT ID FROM employee WHERE Name='"+txt9.getText()+"'),"+
     "(SELECT ID FROM employee WHERE Name='"+txt10.getText()+"')");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You here inserted some double quotation marks in wrong places, please check it, it should work.